# LINQ; how to get a record with max Id using join?

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, join, nhibernate

I want to find one record from a list which should be the MAX (id) of the list. This record is used to show in grid view.

```
 var cacheProducts = nettingOffAudService.All().TOList();

 Product product = productService.FindBy(x => x.ProductName == "NETOFF");

 var MasterRenewal = masterRenewalAudService.All().Where(x => x.ProductSeq == product.Id ).ToList();
```

Here I want to match MasterRenewal's one column with cacheProducts's Id, So i tried like following

```
var jsonData = new
 {
     total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
        from p in cacheProducts 
        join MR in MasterRenewal on p.Id equals MR.MstSeq into MRRenewal
        from MR in MRRenewal.DefaultIfEmpty()

                select new
                {
                    cell = new Object[] 
                    { 
                        p.Id.ToString(),  
                        B.BranchName,
                        p.AccountNumber,
                        p.ClientName,
                        MR==null?"":((enumRecStatusMasterRenewal)MR.RecordStatus).GetDescriptionEnum(),
                        p.Status.GetStatusString(),
                    }
                }).ToArray()
  };
```

If MasterRenewal contains more than one record with the same MstSeq,Then I want to take the last generated record which is MAX (id). For this i tried like following

```
   join MR in MasterRenewal on p.Id equals MR.MstSeq into MRRenewal
   from MR in MRRenewal.Max(x=>x.Id).First().DefaultIfEmpty()
```

But This is not working, So how to do this? Please anybody help.

Comment: Can you share with us with an example input and expected output?

Comment: What is `B.BranchName`?

Comment: Branch is another table, So the id is matched with branch table like following   ===>   var Branch = branchService.All().ToList();       join B in Branch on p.BranchSeq equals B.Id

Comment: Consider Two tables that's NetOff and Renewal. I want to get all records from NetOff table join with Renewal table's MstSeq and ProductSeq Column. Here ProductSeq is same  value, but MstSeq consists different value. And also MstSeq can be duplicates. Here my output is: If MstSeq contains duplicates in Renewal table, then I want to take the maximum id record. @ Doro . please help me if you know the answer

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is the following

```
var uniqueMasterRenewal = MasterRenewal.GroupBy(mr => mr.MstSeq)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(mr => mr.Id).FirstOrDefault());

from p in cacheProducts 
join MR in uniqueMasterRenewal on p.Id equals MR.MstSeq into MRRenewal
from MR in MRRenewal.DefaultIfEmpty()
...
```

That will group the items in `MasterRenewal` by the `MstSeq` then it orders each group by `Id` in descending order so that the `First` item is the item with the maximum value for `Id`.

Comment: This is not working @ Juharr....Here problem is First() method not working properly

Comment: If you're dealing with a SQL Linq provider then you probably need to use `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: @ juharr: It's not working, while running and when debug comes on above give line then it shows the following error:    ===>  could not execute query
[ select masterrene0_.MASTER_RNW_SEQ as MASTER1_142_, masterrene0_.ROUTE_SEQ as ROUTE2_142_, masterrene0_.PRODUCT_SEQ as PRODUCT3_142_, masterrene0_.MST_SEQ as MST4_142_, masterrene0_.REQ_SUBMISSION_DATE as REQ5_142_, ............................................................

Comment: The error is occurring on the "uniqueMasterRenewal " variable

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need a join. A simple subquery should be enough, nowdays database SQL optimizers easily can turn them into joins if needed.

So I would suggest using something like this

```
// ...
from p in cacheProducts 
let MR = MasterRenewal.Where(r => r.MstSeq == p.Id).OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault()
// the rest
```

**Update:** Here is the same with join

```
// ...
from p in cacheProducts
join MR in MasterRenewal on p.Id equals MR.MstSeq into MRRenewal
let MR = MRRenewal.OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).FirstOrDefault()
// the rest
```

I have no idea why you insist on having joins, I've tested both variants on a similar relationship, and they produce one and the same result (with left outer join semantics).

Comment: Yeah, This is ok, But i need to load grid data using join only. Please edit help me to do it using a join  @ Ivan Stoev

Comment: @MdAslam Why do you need to use join only?  If this does what you want I don't see why it isn't a valid solution.

Comment: @MdAslam After posting the answer, I realized that it doesn't directly answer the question as defined in the title. But I think the goal is to get the intended result, not how to get it (assuming it's not an inefficient way). This is the general idea behind the SQL.

Comment: @ Ivan Your post is a valid solution only, But i want to get each record of NetOff table join with Renewal Table. Because If NetOff contains some record and Renewal table is empty then your code is not working.

Comment: @MdAslam `Where(r => r.MstSeq == p.Id)` does the "join". Join is a syntax sugar for matching two table fields for equality.